# Path not found by non-root service

Tags: centos, systemd, services

I have a Centos 7 VPS where I have published a .NET Core application. The solution is ran as a service.

It is published in the path:

```
*/var/opt/MyApp/(All app's files)*
```

At startup it registers a location to log all the info that I need to be logged. The log path is fixed:

```
*/var/log/opt/MyApp/(rotated log file)*
```

I have created a service file under

```
*/etc/systemd/system/MyApp.service*
```

as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=Service MyApp

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/opt/MyApp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/opt/MyApp/MyApp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp
User=myappbe
Group=myappbe
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The myappbe user and group are created with nologin with the following commands:

```
*useradd -l -r -s /sbin/nologin myappbe*
*usermod -a -G myappbe myappbe*
```

The working directory and the log location are both owned by myappbe user and group with 0775 permission.
Running the service configured like this I can see from journalctl an error:

```
*Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Requested trace logging directory 
'/var/log/opt/MyApp/' does not exist*
```

even though that location exists and myappbe is owner.

Changing the User and Group lines in the service to:

```
User=root
Group=root
```

runs the service as root with no errors. And the path is found and i can see the logs being written .

Why is the path not found when running the service as non-root?

Edit*

I have tried commenting the check if the directory exists and going straight to writing the log file and I got the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> '/var/log/opt/MyApp' is denied.

Apparently the user that the service is running under has no permissions on this path. But the permissions are the ones I mentioned earlier.

Comment: `sudo -u myappbe bash` and check if you could access the path yourself, then adjust permissions accordingly

Comment: after executing your command I did:


`cd /var/log/opt/MyApp`

but got the following response 

`bash: cd: /var/log/opt/MyApp: Permission denied`

Tried giving 7777 permissions to that folder but same result

Comment: the command "login" you into shell under the user. It is a way, you could easily check if location is accessible.  Make sure that parent folders allowing the user to access the MyApp folder as well

Comment: ok, thanks for steering me in the right direction.

the var/opt folder had owner root and 0744 permissions. Switched it to 0755 and everything worked.

If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the correct one